# Golang: get not named params

Tags: parameters, go

For example, I have a request:

```
POST /api/users/1/categories/2/posts/3
```

How can I access this params?


I've tried:

```
req.ParseMultipartForm(defaultMaxMemory)

req.Form.Get("id")
req.Form.Get("1")
req.Form.Get("_1")
```

But it doesn't work.


Same question about GET:

```
GET /api/users/1/categories/2/posts/3
```

How to get not named params?

```
req.URL.Query().Get(???)
```

Comment: ParseMultipartForm is for parsing form fields from the request body. You are trying to parse the request URL.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the default http server library, you'll need to parse the Url path parts and extract them.

There are libraries like Gorilla Mux (which I personally like) that you can use to add this logic automatically. http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux

Using Gorilla/mux, when you register your handler, you register it like so:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/api/users/{userId}/categories/{categoryId}/posts/{postId}", 
             MyHandler)
```

And then in your handler you can access them:

```
vars := mux.Vars(request)
userId := vars["userId"]
// etc...
```

Comment: I'm using `martini` and where is this functionality too, but I need get this params in my `middleware`, where it's not working

Comment: @cnaize then you'll need to split the url paths yourself and access them. If you need help with that I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: oh, it will be useful